# How to create Linux service

Tags: java, linux, shell, service

I am trying to run my jar as a service because my server should not shouting down when the system is getting shutdown. So I plan to start the server as a service.

My script is,

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myservice
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# X-Interactive:     true
# Short-Description: Start/stop myservice server
### END INIT INFO

JARPATH="/usr/local/myservice/lib"
PID=$JARPATH/pid

start() {
    echo "Starting myservice ..."
    if [ ! -f $PID ]; then
        nohup java -jar $JARPATH/myservice-1.0.0.jar $JARPATH 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
        echo $! > $PID
        echo "myservice started ..."
    else
        echo "myservice is already running ..."
    fi
}

stop() {
    if [ -f $PID ]; then
        #PID=$(cat /usr/local/myservice/pid);
        echo "Stopping myservice ..."
        kill $(cat "$PID");
        echo "myservice stopped ..."
        rm $PID
    else
        echo "myservice is not running ..."
    fi
}

case $1 in
    start)
        echo $JARPATH
        echo $PID
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
    *)
esac
```

And I did the following steps,

1. sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/myservice
2. sudo update-rc.d myservice defaults

And then start the service using the following command, But the above script is not working...

> sudo service myservice start

Here what did I wrong??
Kindly provide your thoughts.

Comment: What is not working exactly ?

Comment: my server is not running...

Comment: Is there any message when you `sudo service myservice start` ?

Comment: No there are no message..

Comment: please, try to use case "{$1}".
Exmpl: case "${1} in  "start") echo... ;;

Comment: Or add variable `COMMAND="$1"`
and use it in cycle `case $COMMAND in`

Comment: No effects.. both of the above scenario..

Comment: Have you verified that your script works when it is called _not_ through the service manager? That is, if you run "sh /etc/init.d/myservice start" as root, does that behave as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above script works fine when I put a double quotes in $1,

```
case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
    *)
esac
```