# Script guide to prevent duplicate execution of jar in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, executable-jar

Jar should run in the background and not run redundantly.
Even if duplicate execution occurs, all must be terminated

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
ENV=dev
SER_NAME=batch
JAR_FULL=/was/batch/test.jar
case $1 in
    restart)
        if apid=$(pgrep -f $SER_NAME)
        then
            for pid in $apid; do
                echo "Stop $SER_NAME pid : $pid"
                kill -9 $pid
            done
        else
            echo "$SER_NAME is not running ... "
        fi
        nohup java -jar $JAR_FULL --spring.profiles.active=$ENV > /dev/null 2>&1 &
        echo "$SER_NAME" start"
    ;;
    stop)
        if apid=$(pgrep -f $SER_NAME)
        then
            for pid in $apid; do
                echo "Stop $SER_NAME - pid : $pid"
                kill -9 $pid
            done
        else
            echo "$SER_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    start)
        if apid=$(pgrep -f $SER_NAME)
        then
            echo "$SER_NAME is already running ..."
            for pid in $apid; do
                echo "Running $SER_NAME -pid : $pid"
            done
        else
            nohup java -jar $JAR_FULL --spring.profiles.active=$ENV > /dev/null 2>&1 &
            echo "$SER_NAME start!"
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

example) run.sh

> console) chmod 755 run.sh

> console) ./run.sh start

start or stop or restart

Comment: While your question is a bit vague. Your solution is okay... but: On a modern Linux I would strongly suggest to use systemd as shown here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/672609/how-do-you-make-a-process-a-service-under-systemd

Comment: Also don't forget to put double-quotes `"$1"` around your variable. As shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45978321/406423